# How can I find element and insert text on this page?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

The problem is that I cannot find and enter the text in the fields

```
<input onkeyup="$('#firstname').val(this.value);" type="text" class="is_required validate form-control" data-validate="isName" id="customer_firstname" name="customer_firstname" value="" xpath="1">
```

I tried using `id` and `Xpath` but it doesn't work

```
driver.findElement(By.id("customer_firstname")).sendKeys("Mario");
```

Or by Xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='customer_firstname']")).sendKeys("Mario");
```

Any tips? :)

This is the [website](http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account). Insert email -> click 'create an account' -> and there are those fields to fill in to register.

Comment: Do you get any exception or just sent keys do not appear in text box?

Answer (score 2):

Wait for the element before trying to write on it. You can implement the waiting both implicitly and explicitly. The fluent wait is another option.

**Implicit wait:**

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Wait for maximum 10 seconds 
driver.findElement(By.id("customer_firstname")).sendKeys("Mario");
```

**Explicit wait:**

Wait for the element with a specific condition. Here we can wait for the element until the element is visible.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // Wait for maximum 10 seconds
WebElement firstName = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("customer_firstname")));
firstName.sendKeys("Mario");
```

**Fluent wait:**

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
    .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Waiting maximum 10 seconds for presence of the element on the page
    .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Checking for presence in every 2 seconds.
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement firstName = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() 
{
  public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
      return driver.findElement(By.id("customer_firstname"));
  }
});

firstName.sendKeys("Mario");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Xpath expression seems to be fine, may be you need to wait before finding and sending keys into that textbox.

Although `Thread.sleep(5000)` is not  recommended but you could try it to  test if that's the problem.
or try below.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement textBoxCustomer_Name =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("customer_firstname")));
textBoxCustomer_Name.sendKeys("Mario");
```

It will wait till WebElement is loaded inside DOM for 10 seconds at max & will continue once found, before throwing  `NoSuchElement`Exception.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for response I will check the 'fix' this evening :)